# Which games have been based off/derived from the Anime d20 SRD?

Tags: d20-system, dnd-3e, ogl

The Anime d20 SRD brought some interesting changes to the original 3e d20 SRD. Aside from BESM d20, which obviously isn't a derivative of itself, which games have made use of the Anime d20 SRD - in particular the modifications to the base classes, moreso than the new classes that were introduced.

Answer (score 5):

Guardians of Order used it for a variety of subsequent games, like [Slayers d20](http://rpg.drivethrustuff.com/product_info.php?products_id=1466&it=1&affiliate_id=75162&), Hellsing, Trigun, and [Uresia](http://www222.pair.com/sjohn/uresia.htm).  In terms of games from other people, the field is pretty small. [Arakos: The Eighth Age](https://www.rpgnow.com/product_info.php?products_id=20397&affiliate_id=10761&) from Battlefield Press is the only one currently available. [Seraphim Guard](http://www.seraphimguard.com/heroic-ages-iii.php) used it for Heroic Ages III, Banzai! and Heroes of the Floating Worlds - this was long ago and I'm not sure if those games ever saw release.

Reference: [RPG.net list of Anime d20 products](http://index.rpg.net/display-search.phtml?key=system&value=Anime%20d20&sort=publisher) (Omits Slayers for some reason)